# Rails 4 with iframe, bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using  `config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL' }` in main application. If I go to the link `examle.com/example%20?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%` returns "**Bad Request**". 
What's the problem?

Comment: You need to describe the problem in more details. What is examle.com/example%20?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100% Is it your application URL? Are all pages having problem? What are those iframe, height and width params for.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: http://example.com/example%20?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100% - my URL in aplication. Problems arise if there is a url iframe=true. This url from Google Analytics.

Comment: I mean rails log, probably `log/production.log`, depending on env.

Comment: [2014-06-23 15:55:32] ERROR bad URI `/hotel%20?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%'. This  console.

Comment: Whether this problem with the X-Frame-Options?